# How i will write test case for this class ?plz help me

Tags: apex, unit-test

```
public with sharing class CRM_AddProducts {

  public String message {
    get;
    set;
  }

  public String SelectedProduct {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public list < pProduct > lstproduct {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public list < cproduct > cartlstproduct {
    get;
    set;
  }

  public list < CProduct__c > lstselproduct {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public list < CQuote_Line_Item__c > lstaddquoteproduct {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public List < SelectOption > Product_Selectionoptions {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public boolean selected {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public boolean display {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public CProduct__c pro {
    get;
    set;
  }
  // public CProduct__c cpro{get;set;}
  // public CProduct__c cess{get;set;}
  public map < Id, double > mapProductIdToQuantity {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public string strid;
  public boolean blnStatus1;

  public CRM_AddProducts() {
    lstproduct = new list < pProduct > ();
    mapProductIdToQuantity = new map < Id, double > ();
    cartlstproduct = new list < cproduct > ();
    lstaddquoteproduct = new list < CQuote_Line_Item__c > ();
    strid = apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');

    for (CProduct__c objproduct: [select id,
    Name,
    List_Price__c,
    Product_Code__c,
    Product_Description__c,
    Sales_Price__c,
    Product_Family__c
    from CProduct__c]) {
      lstproduct.add(new pProduct(objproduct));
      system.debug('---lstproduct---' + lstproduct);
    }
  }

  public pageReference check() {
    return null;
  }

  //builds a picklist of product names based on their product id
  public List < SelectOption > getProduct_Selection()
  {
    List < SelectOption > Product_Selectionoptions = new List < SelectOption > ();
    //new list for holding all of the picklist options

    for (CProduct__c Product_Selection: [SELECT Id, Name FROM CProduct__c]) {
      //query for Product records 
      Product_Selectionoptions.add(new selectOption(Product_Selection.Id, Product_Selection.Name));

      //for all records found - add them to the picklist options
    }
    system.debug('-Product_Selectionoptions-' + Product_Selectionoptions);
    return Product_Selectionoptions; //return the picklist options
  }

  public pageReference addtocart() {
    for (pProduct cProd: lstproduct) {

      system.debug('----cProd---' + cProd);
      system.debug('--SelectedProduct--' + SelectedProduct);
      system.debug('-Product_Selectionoptions-' + Product_Selectionoptions);
      //  system.debug('-Product_Selection-'+Product_Selectionoptions.Product_Selection);
      if (cProd.selected == true) {
        system.debug('----cProd---' + cProd);
        CProduct__c objproduct1 = [select id, Name,
        List_Price__c,
        Product_Code__c,
        Product_Description__c,
        Sales_Price__c,
        Product_Family__c
        from CProduct__c
        where id = : SelectedProduct];
        cartlstproduct.add(new cproduct(objproduct1));
        system.debug('---cartlstproduct---' + cartlstproduct);
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  public pageReference processSelected() {

    list < CQuote_Line_Item__c > lstaddquoteproduct = new list < CQuote_Line_Item__c > ();
    //   list<CProduct__c> lstselproduct = new list<CProduct__c>();
    system.debug(lstproduct + '===lstproduct====');

    for (cproduct cess: cartlstproduct) {
      system.debug('-----cess---' + cess);
      if (cess.Display == true) {

        if ((cess.quantity != null && cess.quantity != '' && cess.quantity != string.valueof(0)) && (cess.salesprice != null && cess.salesprice != '')) {

          //mapProductIdToQuantity.put(cPro.pro.id,double.valueof(cPro.quantity));
          //system.debug(mapProductIdToQuantity+'---map---');

          CQuote_Line_Item__c objQuoteli = new CQuote_Line_Item__c();
          system.debug('---cess.quantity---' + cess.quantity);
          objQuoteli.Name = cess.cpro.Name;
          objQuoteli.Quantity__c = double.valueOf(cess.quantity);
          objQuoteli.Unit_Price__c = cess.cpro.List_Price__c;
          objQuoteli.Quote__c = strid;
          objQuoteli.Total_Amount__c = double.valueof(cess.TotalAmount);
          //objQuoteli.Discount_Percent__c = double.valueOf(cess.discount) ;
          objQuoteli.Sales_Price__c = double.valueOf(cess.salesprice);
          system.debug('---objQuoteli---' + objQuoteli);
          lstaddquoteproduct.add(objQuoteli);
          system.debug(lstaddquoteproduct + '----lstaddquoteproduct----');
        } else {
          system.debug('---else---');
          ApexPages.Message errormessage = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Please enter all the values.');
          ApexPages.addMessage(errormessage);
        }
      }
    } //for loop
    if (lstaddquoteproduct.size() > 0) {
      insert lstaddquoteproduct;
      system.debug('---strid--' + strid);
      pageReference pageRef1 = new pageReference('/' + strid);
      pageRef1.setredirect(true);
      return pageRef1;
    }
    return null;
  }

  //product list wrapper class

  public class pProduct {
    public CProduct__c pro {
      get;
      set;
    }
    public boolean selected {
      get;
      set;
    }
    public string quantity {
      get;
      set;
    }
    public string salesprice {
      get;
      set;
    }
    public integer TotalAmount {
      get;
      set;
    }
    public string discount {
      get;
      set;
    }
    public pProduct(CProduct__c p) {
      pro = p;
      selected = false;
      quantity = '1';
    }
  }

  //cart list wrapper class

  public class cproduct {
    public CProduct__c cpro {
      get;
      set;
    }
    public boolean selected {
      get;
      set;
    }
    public boolean Display {
      get;
      set;
    }
    public string quantity {
      get;
      set;
    }
    public string salesprice {
      get;
      set;
    }
    public string TotalAmount {
      get;
      set;
    }
    public string discount {
      get;
      set;
    }

    public cProduct(CProduct__c c) {
      cpro = c;
      selected = false;
      quantity = '1';
      salesprice = string.valueof(cpro.List_Price__c);
      TotalAmount = string.valueof(cpro.List_Price__c);
      Display = false;
    }
  }

  public pageReference cancelbutton() {
    pageReference pageRef1 = new pageReference('/' + strid);
    pageRef1.setredirect(true);
    return pageRef1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Amit, you'll have to specify your question. Let's start at the beginningof writing test classes - have you gone through the documentation ? Do you know how you should write test classes ? Is there a specific part of your code you're not sure how to test ?   Consider that with specific questions like that, you can break down the process of writing test classes, and look up the individual challenges. We'd like to help,but in order to do so it helps us if you tell us where you're blocked in the process.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @SamuelDeRycke , I know how to write a test class but in this class two wrapper class is used . i am not able to understand how to test case for a wrapper  class so please give me solution for that .

Comment: For wrapper classes without logic you can just make an instance of it with appropriate properties and that'll do it. When there's logic involved, test for every method. It's the same as any other class.

Comment: I am not getting can you please write some example ...

Comment: ok... but it'll be an example and until we know what is specifically challenging to you .. we can't answer that specifically.

Answer (score 1):

You can test wrapper classes like any class.

```
public wrap {
    public string sauce {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public int size {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public wrap(string sauce, int size) {
        this.sauce = sauce;
        this.size = size;
    }
    public take_a_bite() {
        this.size--;
    }

}
```

So you test:

```
//create an instance
Wrap wr= new Wrap('guacamole',5);
//verify stuff happens
System.assertEquals('guacamole',wr,'something went wrong with the sauce');
System.assertEquals(5,wr.size,'we didn't get the right size);

wr.take_a_bite();
System.assertEquals(4, wr.size,'infinite food is a problem!');
```

Try to test your sub-wrapper classes separately, and test all functional methods, just like you'd test any other apex class.